# Coordinator layout, нижний слой налазит на верхний

Tags: android, coordinator-layout

Есть Coordinator layout в котором 3 элемента

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_tab">
    </FrameLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottom_tab"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorAccent"
        app:tabIndicatorHeight="?attr/actionBarSize" 
        android:background="@color/white">

    </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

FrameLayout отрисовывается поверх toolbar, а TabLayout поверх FrameLayout, а нужно что бы FrameLayout был между toolbar и TabLayout, что бы FrameLayout ничто не перекрывало и он ничто не перекрывал. Как это сделать?
**Нужно именно в CoordinatorLayout.**

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте `FrameLayout` прописать поведение стандартное:

`app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">`

Comment: Спасибо стало лучше но bottom_tab все равно перекрывает часть main_container. main_container привязал к bottom_tab

Comment: @AstendSanferion можно вынести `TabLayout` за пределы `CoordinatorLayout` вниз